# How to get all possible android device information by connecting device to PC using USB connection

Tags: android, usb, adb

I want to create a desktop application which will show all the possible information about running application on android device.

The information can be CPU & battery usage, network consumption, running threads, etc.

The android device will be connected to PC using USB cable.
I've tried using ADB commands but didn't get more information. Is there any other ways.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when you look into the `proc` file system.
You can get the information in the following way from the host machine.

1. **CPU Information**

   ```
   $ adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo
   Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
   Hardware    : Qualcomm MSM 8226 (Flattened Device Tree)
   Revision    : 83c0
   Serial      : 2458ab020f000000
   Device      : falcon
   Radio       : 5
   MSM Hardware    : MSM8226 CS
   ```

   Similarly use `/proc/meminfo` for memory information
2. **Battery Information**

   ```
   $ adb shell cat /sys/class/power_supply/battery/uevent
   POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=battery
   POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGING_ENABLED=1
   POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Charging
   POWER_SUPPLY_CHARGE_TYPE=Fast
   POWER_SUPPLY_HEALTH=Good
   POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
   POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=20
   POWER_SUPPLY_TEMP=305
   ```
3. **Network Consumption**
   You can check for the *total* Network consumption for the device using the following.
   I have listed only two interfaces `lo` and `wlan`. This command will list all the Interface information

   ```
   $ adb shell cat /proc/net/dev
   Inter-|   Receive                                                |  Transmit
   face  |bytes    packets errs drop fifo frame compressed multicast|bytes    packets errs drop fifo colls carrier compressed
   lo:   71374     797    0    0    0     0          0         0    71374     797    0    0    0     0       0          0
   wlan0: 17974070   17833    0    2    0     0          0         0  1329415   11832    0    0    0     0       0          0
   ```
4. **Running Thread Information**
   You can get running thread information using `ps` with `-t`

   ```
   $ adb shell ps -t
   USER     PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS     WCHAN    PC         NAME
   u0_a96    3396  15236 602668 57668 ffffffff 00000000 S Timer-1
   u0_a96    3402  15236 602668 57668 ffffffff 00000000 S Thread-5083
   u0_a96    3403  15236 602668 57668 ffffffff 00000000 S com.whatsapp
   u0_a96    3404  15236 602668 57668 ffffffff 00000000 S com.whatsapp
   ```

If you dig a little more into `/proc` and `/sys` you can get more information.
[Here](http://rhcelinuxguide.wordpress.com/2006/06/03/overview-on-the-proc-file-system/) is a good article about it.

Tested on: `Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS` and `Motorola Moto G` connected via USB.

Comment: @Sourabh I've already mentioned that "I've tried using ADB commands but didn't get more information. Is there any other ways."
The response of ADB commands is very slow and it is affecting my application's overall performance.

Actually, I'm trying to get all possible information from device per second.

If possible help me with the alternate ways.

Comment: @Android, Can you verify if you are connected via ADB, maybe using `adb devices` or `adb shell`. 

Are the above commands working for you (atleast once) ?

Since you are creating an application on your Host machine, connected to the phone via USB, IMHO `adb` is your best bet.

Comment: @Sourabh Yes, I've connected device with PC using ADB.

Comment: Also, ADB gives raw data that we need to parse which can vary between different OS versions.

Comment: @Android, Are any of the above commands working for your device ?
ADB will give you the same data irrespective of your Host OS.

Comment: @Sourabh I'm not talking about Host OS, ADB commands response varies depending on Android OS version. You can check "adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo" on 2.3 and later versions.

And I've implemented my application using ADB commands but now I'm having performance issue.

Comment: Are the above commands working for your device ? If yes, what are the Issues you are facing ? Please be specific.

Comment: I've used dumpsys commands instead of /proc file. Now I'm having performance issue. Specially while getting thread info. It is taking 3-4 seconds to give response. I want each CPU usage of each thread of any application.

Comment: @Android, I would suggest you to edit the question, adding info as why `adb` didn't work and info about your target device and Host Machine

Since this is turning to be a performance issue, It would be helpful to add info (in the question) about how you are reading data at your desktop application running at host.